# Why ProductHunt api dont work with Python?

Tags: python, django, pip

Why i can not work with Product Hunt api in python. My api key is correct

```
`ph = ProductHunt(api_key='WUY0eh1BU_-BnIOtYcFBSEk2UuwUsFCTOXzbZe0CYFY')
daily_products = ph.get_daily()`
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\eesca\PyProjects\solkit\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    daily_products = ph.get_daily()
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\eesca\PyProjects\solkit\.venv\Lib\site-packages\producthunt\producthunt.py", line 41, in get_daily
    products = data.get('data', {}).get('posts', {}).get('edges', [])
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```